# how to make installation package for my framework like .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have built a framework to develop my window application by C#. Now I want to make an installation for that framework like the installation for .NET framework. Could I do it?

Comment: try creating a Nuget package

Comment: Thank Mitch Wheat a lot, i am trying your suggest, and let you know the result later.

Comment: create a setup project, add it to your solution, add necessary dependencies, additional files, etc... this will create a .msi installer package which you can install or deploy. to create a .exe installer i usually just create a console project which starts a process to run the .msi with /qb option. also do some checks on dotnet version, and bypass the default .msi dotnet installer, as its problematic.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest, now my framework can install to the target computer like the .net framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to deploy your application on target machines, you can read a summary for them on the [MSDN webpage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbb4k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you are talking about your custom .Net framework entirely based upon .Net you need to ensure that your assemblies are installed into GAC (global assembly cache) on every machine, so they can be automatically discovered and bound. You can read about this process [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

On the other side, if this is just a code, you might think of something like [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/), a packet manager for .Net, as suggested in the comment.

Comment: Thank Alexander Galkin a lots, i am trying to follow your answer. Will tell you the result later.

Comment: Now i can make an installation for my framework and also add the assembly to the GAC. Everything is good, there is just an issue that i am facing with that the assembly can not be found in the add reference dialog. To do that i have to add the registry key by manually. Do you have any hint for me to fix that?

Comment: Look at this link, maybe this is what you are looking for: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306149